# Magento: Facebook purchase tracking - without duplicate base code

Tags: facebook, magento

I've setup my webshop with the Facebook Pixel code (with the standard 'PageView' event) in the header so it appears on all pages. In addition to that, I have inserted the same Facebook Pixel base code + 'Purchase' event on the success page via success.phtml found in app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/checkout

So the base Pixel code is there two times on the success page. It works, but I am looking for a better way of doing it, where the basecode is only there once on the success page.

Can anyone help with that? :)

To illustrate - this is how it is setup up now:

**All pages across the website:**

(in the head)

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

**Success page:**

(in the head)

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

(in the body)

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '<?php echo $grandTotal; ?>', currency: 'DKK'});</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

And this is how I want it to be on the success page:

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('track', "PageView");
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '<?php echo $grandTotal; ?>', currency: 'DKK'});</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already have Google Analytics setup, and if you have Google Tag Manager along with it, I reckon best is to use Google Tag Manager to install FB pixel to your site, Look at the following link,

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1021909254506499

Doing this may help with bit of a site speed improvement as well.

Comment: Awesome!!, didn't knew thats even possible through GTM!